# listening to click on specific element in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a question about the angular concept. I ask it with an example.

For example, I have some links similar to these items in my off-canvas menu:

```
<ul class="my_ul">
    <li> <a (click)="do1()">do1</a> </li>
    <li> <a (click)="do2()">do2</a> </li>
    <li> <a (click)="do3()">do3</a> </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I want to know when user click on `ul.my_ul > li > a` then I run `closeOffcanvas()` function.

- I don't want to add my `closeOffcanvas()` into the `do1()` or `do2()` or ...
- I don't want to create a `directive`.
- I don't want to add 2 function like: `(click)="do1(); closeOffcanvas()"`

---

To get what I mean: In `jquery` I can do this: **(without any html change)**

```
$('ul.my_ul > li > a').click(function(){
    //my close off-canvas codes
});
```

How can I do similar this in Angular?

### I want to listen to events of a specific element list in component without change HTML.

**note:** please don't solve the example problem. it isn't my problem. it is only an example to explain my mean.

Comment: You can add the (click) on the ul this way you'd get the event everytime the user clicks on any li.

I understand this isn't exactly what you need but it should achieve the same purpose

Comment: @m_sultan the problem is an example. I want to listen to a specific element event. I want to know the user click on which `a` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I summarize the final and best answer:

First, we access the elements with `ElementRef`, like this:

```
const elements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ul.class_name li > a");
```

then we listen to element's events with `Renderer2`, like this:

```
elements.forEach( element => {
    this.renderer.listen(element, "click", event => {
        //do something...
    });
});
```

---

Don't forget to import these:

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
```

and:

```
constructor( private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2 ){ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using HostListener, Renderer2 or you can give the ul-element the click event.

Here is an example for the last solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfnohf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

---

With the event, you can see, which element was clicked

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  do1() {
    console.log('do1');
  }
  do2() {
    console.log('do2');
  }
  do3() {
    console.log('do3');
  }  

  closeOffcanvas(event) {
    if(event.target.matches('a'))
    {
      console.log('user clicked on: ', event.target, 'with name: ', event.target.innerHTML);
    }    
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="my_ul" (click)="closeOffcanvas($event)">
    <li> <a (click)="do1()">do1</a> </li>
    <li> <a (click)="do2()">do2</a> </li>
    <li> <a (click)="do3()">do3</a> </li>
</ul>
```

---

**update** example without changing html

It is better not binding an event for all list items. The performance is much greater if you only bind a wrapper-element and check if the event.target is the right children-element

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oqjstq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

---

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use `ElementRef` to select elements in the current component, like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li><a (click)="do1()">do1</a></li>
      <li><a (click)="do2()">do2</a></li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const elements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ul > li > a");
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.addEventListener("click", this.doCommon);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    const elements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ul > li > a");
    elements.forEach(element => {
      element.removeEventListener("click", this.doCommon);
    });
  }

  do1() { console.log("do1"); }
  do2() { console.log("do2"); }
  doCommon() { console.log("common"); }

}
```

If you don't want to limit your query to the contents of the current component, you can replace `this.elementRef.nativeElement` with `document`.

I haven't used it in the past, but it works fine in my [StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cxhnw).

Maybe this whole `ngOnDestroy()` to prevent memory leaks isn't necessary in modern browsers, but I still feel a little safer by doing it :)

Comment: thanks, perfect. but you used pure javascript `addEventListener`, that it does not work when <a> has a route and page change. `Renderer2` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the parent reference, treat the parent as a collection, iterate over it and assign event listeners. (In Angular syntax you can use **HostListener**).

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fsjhu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html